# Python code asks again after a enter the right input

Tags: python-3.x

Running this code I need to enter a fraction and the code will return a percentage like a fuel tank, or it will return E or F.
So when I enter 1/2 it returns 50%.
If I enter 1/1 it will return F.

The code has to request new input if the fraction is wrong, like 2/1. But after that, if I enter the right input, the code request input again, and I would like to know why.

(base) @user:~/Desktop$ python fuel.py

Fraction:2/1

Fraction:1/2

Fraction:1/5

20%

```
def main():
    fraction = get_fraction()
    if fraction > 0.9:
        print("F")
    elif fraction < 0.1:
        print("E")
    else:
        print("%i%%" % int(round(fraction * 100)))

def get_fraction():
    while True:
        try:
            fraction = input("Fraction:")
            up, down = fraction.split("/")
            if int(up) > int(down):
                get_fraction()
            else:
                return float(up) / float(down)
        except ValueError or ZeroDivisionError:
            pass


main()
```

I tried to input 2/1 so the code would request again the right input.
So I entered 1/2 but instead get the percentage, the code request input again

Answer (score 2):

This is because you call get_fraction() recursively. Replace the call of get_fraction() by continue.